# error adding host side routes for interface

Tags: kubernetes

Today I find a warning events in kubernetes 1.26 cluster, the message like this:

```
Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "b9d79cdbb4b22f24560ed1d6d4f918562084754fb4b0e3293d194537701bd71d": plugin type="calico" failed (add): error adding host side routes for interface: caliad77b3f309b, error: route (Ifindex: 414, Dst: 10.97.196.207/32, Scope: link) already exists for an interface other than 'caliad77b3f309b': route (Ifindex: 17, Dst: 10.97.196.207/32, Scope: link, Iface: calif0b886c45c0)
```

why did this error happen? what should I do to fixed this issue? the calico version is `docker.io/calico/kube-controllers:v3.26.1`. This is the kubernetes deployment defined:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dolphin-post-service
  namespace: reddwarf-pro
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dolphin-post-service
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: dolphin-post-service
      annotations:
        kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: '2023-09-23T03:14:16Z'
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: dolphin-post-service-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: dolphin-post-service-pv-claim-new
      containers:
        - name: dolphin-post-service
          image: >-
            registry.cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/dolphin-post:618bea964d64cb368f2c4553eb4c2b475e73c64f
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: APOLLO_META
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: pro-apollo-config
                  key: apollo.meta
            - name: ENV
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: pro-apollo-config
                  key: env
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 800m
              memory: 600Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 256Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: dolphin-post-service-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /root/data
              mountPropagation: HostToContainer
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health/liveness
              port: 11014
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 190
            timeoutSeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 30
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health
              port: 11014
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 160
            timeoutSeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 30
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext: {}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: hongkong-regcred
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
```